# BlackBerry Playbook Simulator not working

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook

I developed an Android application on Eclipse, and now I am trying to port it to BlackBerry. I have my signing keys and my certificates, the Eclipse BlackBerry plugin, and the BlackBerry Tablet simulator.

When Eclipse uploads my app to the Playbook simulator, it opens the app but an "Initializing, please wait..." message comes up. After a couple minutes of just sitting there, it exits and goes back to the home screen, where the app is CLEARLY installed. Eclipse gets stuck at 70% of uploading the app. Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using 
"c:\Program Files\Research In Motion\blackberry-tablet-sdk-1.1.1\bin\blackberry-deploy.bat"? Maybe you'll see more information there

Have you tried telnet or SSH to the device and looking at the `/apps`?

Comment: I'm using the Eclipse BlackBerry plugin to upload them. I've also tried using the Graphical Aid, neither way works.

Comment: Tried that as well. The application is uploaded but when I open it, it just stays at "Initializing, Please Wait..." for several minutes.

Comment: Then you need to look at the `air-trace` under `/apps/....`. And if all assets been included in the .bar file